# I can't find why background-origin property not working?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I use `background-origin:content-box`. It should cover only the content area, but it covers the right padding+border area also. What happened?

From my [codepen](https://codepen.io/nur49/pen/jOrpmBy) at  https://codepen.io/nur49/pen/jOrpmBy ...

```css
#backgr {
  background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSExg6qzYza-IFtjglPRkSw5h0el5_Bii1KaQ&usqp=CAU');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  border:10px dashed yellow;
  padding:10px;
  background-origin:content-box ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="backgr">
    <p>
   Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh.Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. D. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudi
    </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Image link totally ok. I use it sololearn app, chrome. Same result. And also try with different image. Nothing change

Comment: is it necessary? - https://ibb.co/0tm6pnX

Comment: Works? But why not in codepen,chrome/sololearn?

Comment: do you need such a result? -  https://ibb.co/0tm6pnX

Comment: Yes. Please help to correction my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `background-clip` or adapt `background-size` to not overflow :

```css
#backgr,
.backgr {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSExg6qzYza-IFtjglPRkSw5h0el5_Bii1KaQ&usqp=CAU');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 10px dashed yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* two option to fix this */
#backgr {
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.backgr {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgr">
  <p>
    Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Lacus viverra
    vitae congue eu consequat. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh.Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque.
    Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. D. Integer feugiat
    scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim
    sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudi
  </p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="backgr">
  <p>
    Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Lacus viverra
    vitae congue eu consequat. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh.Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque.
    Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. D. Integer feugiat
    scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Eget mi proin sed libero enim
    sed faucibus. Ut eu sem integer vitae. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudi
  </p>
</div>
```

`background-origin` will not clip or crop your image, it only set its origin position. Your try sets the top left origin fine, but will not crop it where it overflows.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin
>
> The `background-origin` CSS property sets the background's origin: from the border start, inside the border, or inside the padding.examples
>
> **Note** that `background-origin` is ignored when `background-attachment` is `fixed`.